# How to get method annotations on a proxied class?

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

I have a problem while reading annotations off methods of a proxied class.

There is an interface, an object and an annotation on a method, this part is really simple:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface A {
}

interface I {
    void method();
}

class Test implements I {
    @A
    public void method() { }
}
```

Next, there is an `InvocationHandler` that does nothing, just simply calls the method with the arguments passed:

```java
class DefaultInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(final Object o, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        return method.invoke(o, args);
    }
}
```

And there is a `main` method that prints declared methods of a `Test` instance and its proxied counterpart:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object test = new Test();
        printMethods(test);         // Outputs that `I#method` has `A` annotation

        System.out.println();

        Object proxied = Proxy.newProxyInstance(test.getClass().getClassLoader(), test.getClass().getInterfaces(), new DefaultInvocationHandler());
        printMethods(proxied);      // Outputs that `I#method` does not have `A` annotation
    }

    static void printMethods(Object obj) {
        Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                .forEach(method -> System.out.println(method.toString() + " has A annotation: " + method.isAnnotationPresent(A.class)));
    }
}
```

And here comes the problem: local variable `test` has is an instance of `Test` class, and local variable `proxied` is actually a `Proxy`, so it does not have any annotations on its methods. Here's the output of the program:

```java
public void Test.method() has A annotation: true                // <- good thing

public final boolean $Proxy2.equals(java.lang.Object) has A annotation: false
public final java.lang.String $Proxy2.toString() has A annotation: false
public final void $Proxy2.method() has A annotation: false      // <-  bad thing
public final int $Proxy2.hashCode() has A annotation: false
```

I've tried searching for the solution, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939912/java-how-to-get-annotations-from-proxy-class) is about extracting annotations off an annotation (I presume), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489664/how-do-i-get-the-real-annotation-instead-of-a-proxy-from-constraintdescriptorg) is too about annotation class. [Some of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979717/losing-class-custom-annotation-for-proxy-classes) are about other proxy implementations.

➥ So, is there any way to get actual annotations off a proxied object, or to expose the class that is hidden under the proxy (I want the former one, though)?

Comment: A note if you missed it, in `method.invoke(o, args)`, the `o` is the `Proxy` instance. That invocation is going to go into an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: Why should the proxy have the `A` annotation? The proxy is an implementation of `I`, without any relationship to the `Test` class, so why should the annotation from an unrelated class spill over to the proxy?

Comment: @Holger, yes, now I get it, thanks. Several hours earlier I thought it `Proxy` is a wrapper to the `Test` instance, but now I see that it is the `InvocationHandler` which may hold reference to the proxied object. I should have read the documentation prior to jumping straight to examples. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there any way to get actual annotations off a proxied object,
>   or to expose the class that is hidden under the proxy (I want the
>   former one, though)?

Not directly, no.

The idea behind `Proxy`'s design is that the actual wrapped instance (*if there even is one*) would be hidden behind the invocation handler. You can see this from the `newProxyInstance` method: there's no reference to the `test` instance passed anywhere. The `Proxy` instance has no knowledge of your `Test` instance.

A common pattern is to use a common `InvocationHandler` subclass that keeps a reference to a wrapped instance and can return it to you and you can use that to perform your checks. For example,

```
abstract class InvocationHandlerWithTarget implements InvocationHandler {
    protected final Object target;

    public InvocationHandlerWithTarget(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public Object getTarget() {
        return target;
    }
}

class DefaultInvocationHandler extends  InvocationHandlerWithTarget {
    public DefaultInvocationHandler(Object target) {
        super(target);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(final Object o, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        return method.invoke(target, args);
    }
}
```

and then check if you're working with a `Proxy` and whether its `InvocationHandler` is what you expect

```
Object proxied = Proxy.newProxyInstance(test.getClass().getClassLoader(), test.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            new DefaultInvocationHandler(test));

[...]

if (Proxy.isProxyClass(proxied.getClass())) {
    var handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxied);
    if (handler instanceof InvocationHandlerWithTarget) {
        var handlerWithTarget = (InvocationHandlerWithTarget) handler;

        // now process the target
        handlerWithTarget.getTarget();
    }
}
```

You then have a concrete instance with which to reflect on (or whatever other processing you need to do).

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer! It turned out I was using proxies the wrong way. Now that you have pointed out there is no reference to the `test` within the proxy instance, it looks obvious, but when I was reading examples and writing this piece of code I was completely oblivious to this fact. :/ Thanks again for the explanation! :D